ColorOS: How to get rid of black-pattern "Metis" that I don't want?
The last update to ColorOS 13 brought some new ap, obviously named "metis".
In the morning when the phone awakes me via alarm clock, that metis app overlays the alarm clock, so it's hard to silence it (it was even difficult to make the screen shot):

(I found an English screen shot in [APP] "Metis" app daily pop up)
The app wants me to agree to use location and mobile data to provide some service I don't use or need; there fore I did not agree.
In that app I can only "continue" if I agree to use location data.
However that metis app pops up that screen about every second day since being installed, so I consider this to be a "black pattern", forcing me to agree to something I don't want actually.
The only way to "silence" the app seems to agree.
I checked the app list, but that app isn't listed, so I could not disable it or uninstall it.
Thus the question:
How can I "silence" that popup forever (without agreeing, of course)?

Once knowing that it's a "System App" I found the answer:
Settings -> Apps -> App-Management, then the "..." menu (that was the non-obvious part), then select "System-Apps anzeigen" (show system apps).
Then after scrolling down the list, locate "Metis" and disable it.
